# Should expanded search tools collapse automatically after searching?

Tags: layout, search

We have a page with a list of elements and a hidden advanced search panel that slides down after the user clicks a button. With the advanced search panel hidden, the user will see two rows of results (8 items). After it slides down, the user will only see one row of results (4 items).

If a user fills out the advanced search form and starts a search, then should the panel slide up and close automatically so they have more space for the results, or should the search panel remain in place for the users to close it manually after they are done with searching?

Comment: Hello @trix87, welcome to UX.SE. I've cleaned up your question just a bit, but feel free to [edit] it again if I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to design it in a way, in which, despite the fact that it is open, it will not take up much space & user attention.

4 elements are not enough, you can enter the functionality that will allow you to display x (show with select) - depending on the user's preferences

Maybe checking the frequency and ratio of using advanced search will provide useful data.

**Modeling on Google:**

when you click "Narzędzia" (Tools) it's open 4 selects with additional searching options, at the time of selection the menu does not hide and the selected option changes the font thickness

[image]